# Esperar que for loop/axios termine para llamar la siguiente funcion JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, promesas

Tengo una funcion donde este iterando un array, el mismo va a tener N elementos, los mismos los obtengo de una tabla, dentro del `for loop` tengo `axios` (Axios es un HTTP simple basado en promesas), el cual envio datos a mi controlador, este me devuelve un respuesta:

```
for (let i = 0; i < NumberFacFinal.length; i++) {

                axios.get("EnviarCCFF", {
                    params: {
                        ruta: rutaEnviar,
                        fecha: fechaEnviar,
                        fac: NumberFacFinal[i]

                    }
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data);

                        respuestaTotal =response.data;

                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);

                        respuestaTotal = error.data;
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: "Factura!",
                            text: respuestaTotal,
                            timer: 2000,
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        })
                    });

            }

            CargarNuevasFacturas(rutaEnviar);
```

Mi problema esta en la funcion "`CargarNuevasFacturas(rutaEnviar)`" se ejecuta antes de que obtengan por ejemplo "3/8/9 respuestas por cada posicion del array", como puedo ejecutar la ultima funcion hasta que todas las llamadas o el `for` haya finalizado?